# Correlating an NServiceBus Saga with ConversationId

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

I currently have a some sagas that pass around a custom CorrelationId on a base message class. All events and commands inherit from that base class and so have easy access to the CorrelationId. As a result, the `ConfigureHowToFindSaga` mappings look something like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga(SagaPropertyMapper<MySagaData> mapper)
{
     mapper.ConfigureMapping<MyCommand>(message => message.CorrelationId)
        .ToSaga(sagaData => sagaData.CorrelationId);   

    mapper.ConfigureMapping<MyEvent>(message => message.CorrelationId)
        .ToSaga(sagaData => sagaData.CorrelationId);    
}
```

In each step of the saga (and the other services that the saga communicates with) the custom CorrelationId is currently manually mapped from message to message like so:

```
   public Task Handle(MyCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
   { 
      // do something 

      return context.Publish(new MyEvent { CorrelationId = message.CorrelationId });
   }
```

I was wondering if I could use the NSB `ConversationId` message header to replace the custom CorrelationId as I believe NSB already maps this from message to message automatically.

**I had two questions relating to this:**
1. Does this sound reasonable?
2. If it does, is there a simple way set up the `ConfigureMapping` mappings so that the saga will read from the `context.MessageHeaders[Headers.ConversationId]` rather than directly from a property on the message body?   I realise I could write a custom SagaFinder to dig into the headers and get the ConversationId and use that to then find the saga. However, I thought that if I needed to do this for every saga then maybe the whole approach is wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The saga mapping property's intention is to provide a unique identifier of to the Saga from a business aspect, i.e bank transaction, order id, claimid, or another example might be loan id. so relaying on a technical identifier sounds like you are going down the wrong direction...

What is your business story for those sagas?

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  Up until now we have used a randomly generated CorrelationId for our sagas, which is why I wondered if I could piggy back on the ConversationId. But having a business Id will be more beneficial as I will be able to easily tie it back to the operation it relates to. The business scenario is the import of leads into a CRM system.  We have a LeadId, but that will not work as a Lead can be imported several times (where the import only partially succeeds) so I need something like a  LeadImportSessionId to be introduced.